# NullPointerException when use the PBCTypeDCurveGenerator of jPBC

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Recently, I need to use jPBC to implement a bilinear pairing. But when I Use the Type D Curves just as the http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/docs/ecpg.html#TypeD says. I encountered the Null Pointer Exception. Can you help me out ？  Thanks a lot.

Here is the code :

```
  public class JPBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int discriminant = 9563;
        PBCTypeDCurveGenerator dg = new PBCTypeDCurveGenerator(discriminant);
        dg.generate();   //<<<-------------goes wrong !
     }
}
```

Here is the hint:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pbc.curve.PBCTypeDCurveGenerator.pbcGenerate(PBCTypeDCurveGenerator.java:19)
    at it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pbc.curve.PBCCurveGenerator.generate(PBCCurveGenerator.java:17)
    at JPBC.main(JPBC.java:10)
```

Comment: What's in PBCTypeDCurveGenerator.java at line 19?

Comment: The documentation says `// Init the generator...` I believe you skipped that part, hence the NPE.

Comment: Something is going wrong with `.generate()` function. Something more probably has to be done to initialize the `dg` object before generate can be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

Create a variable of PBCTypeDCurveGenerator  and initialize the value with the value returned from dg.generate().